# Variable Ionic not found

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I get a 'Ionic not found' error when trying to run a Cordova app together with Ionic. 'ionic' is present in the module dependencies and I think I include the right files in de index.html:

```
lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js
lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js
cordova.js
```

I've been searching for hours now and I really don't know what could possibly cause the problem. Anyone knows what could be the matter?

When I inject Ionic in the controller's function, I get a IonicProvider unknown error

The app definition:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('flightDocumentsCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer, $timeout, $cordovaInAppBrowser) {
```

Comment: Have a look in the console (F12) - any resource that can't be loaded? What resources do you load? Possible to provide some more information in order to find the cause...

Comment: The console doesn't show any errors. All resources can be loaded. The resources that I load are listed above.

Comment: Please update your question with your app module definition (`angular.module('yourAppName', ['yourAppDependencies'])`) and your controller module definition.